# Confused about proof that if graph G is 3-connected and |G| > 4, then it has an edge that, when contracted, produces another 3-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I've been trying to understand the proof of the theorem in my textbook, however I'm stuck at one part of the proof

[image]

The first part of the proof assumes that such an edge doesn't exist. This means that for all edges in G, contracting the edge will result in a graph that is less than 3-connected. Therefore, G/xy will have a separator (A set of vertices that disconnects G) of size at most 2.

I don't understand the next part that says that the contracted edge is a member of the separator. Could someone please explain to me why this is the case?

Thank You

Comment: If it weren't the case, then $S$ would also be a separating set of $G$, and since $|S|=2$, we would get a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. S already is a separating set of G/xy. My question is, how do we know that the contracted vertex is part of that separating set? Why can't some other vertex be part of S instead?

Comment: I mean, I can only repeat my comment. Let's assume that the contracted vertex is not in $S$. Then $S=\{z,t\}$ where $z$, $t$ are vertices in $G$. $\{z,t\}$ is separating in $G_{/xy}$, but you can check (exercise!) that $\{z,t\}$ is also separating in $G$. Then, $G$ is at most $2$-connected, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I can't beleive that I didnt' get it earlier. Thank You very much for the help